# To TagSet or not to TagSet when using MakeBoxes

Tags: boxes, guidelines, format

What is the difference between the following two:

```
(*1: UpSet definition*)
myfuncF /: MakeBoxes[myfuncF[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := 
  RowBox[{"f(", Sequence @@ Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {a, b}], ","], ")"}]
```

and

```
(*2: MakeBoxes definition*)
MakeBoxes[myfuncF[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := 
  RowBox[{"f(", Sequence @@ Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {a, b}], ","], ")"}]
```

With `myfuncF[a,b] // TraditionalForm` I get for both the following output.

> *f(a, b)*

Is one preferable over the other?

Comment: One observation here which I find interesting is that `MakeBoxes` is `HoldAllComplete`. This *should* mean that it doesn't perform any `UpValue` search. Yet, `UpValue`-based definitions do work with it. There must be something rather interesting going on there, but I never had the energy to investigate deeper.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I remember from playing around some time ago that these don't set upvalues or downvalues but format values. If I remember correctly these are tried in the logical order but only after downvalues

Comment: @QuantumDot if this is the case I would use the UpSet definition because once you clear myfuncF the definition is cleared too, but it doesn't seem like a big deal anyway

Comment: @Rojo It turns out I can format things like $f^2(x,y)$ by using `MakeBoxes[Power[myfuncF[a_, b_], n_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["f", ToBoxes[n]], "(", Sequence @@ Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {a, b}], ","], ")"}]`, which I cannot do using UpSet (since `myfuncF` would be too deep).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin see my comment above to Rojo

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, this is understandable. But my main point in that comment was in an apparent deviation for the semantics of `UpValues` in the case of `MakeBoxes`.

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, in that case the ideal solution is not an option because its too deep. Either that or associating the definition to TraditionalForm

Comment: @LeonidShifrin if you force them to be upvalues and not format values by setting them as `UpValues[...]=...`, then they don't get checked as far as I can tell

Comment: @Rojo Interesting observation, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, that `TagSetDelayed` form is preferable, as the rule is attached to the `myfuncF` rather than to `MakeBoxes`. This means:

1. `Clear[f]` will remove the `FormatValues`.
2. The pattern is only matched against expressions which contain myfuncF rather than all expressions.
3. The pattern won't compete against any other patterns attached to MakeBoxes (i.e, it's applied first)

As pointed out in some of the comments, this may not work if you have a specific rule for when myfuncF is embedded inside another expression.  In that case you'll need to either attach the rule to that other head, or live with it being attached to `MakeBoxes`.

Note that whether you use `SetDelayed` or `TagSetDelayed`, neither an up value or a down value is created, but rather a format value.