# How do I use the third and fourth arguments of Parenthesize?

Tags: output-formatting, boxes

`Parenthesize` seems to do a good job with constructing boxes that need to be appropriately parenthesized:

```
RowBox[Parenthesize[#, TraditionalForm, Null, Null] & /@ {a, a + b, c}]
% // DisplayForm // TraditionalForm
```

> [image]

I didn't know what to put in the final two arguments of `Parenthesize` so I just put `Null`.  It seems to work without problems.

But it would be nice to know what they do.  Does anybody know?

---

I learned about its existence by seeing how the boxes for `InverseFunction` is made:

```
InverseFunction (*To load box definitions*)

<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[InverseFunction]
```

Then scroll down to the penultimate definition, and you'll see (inside the `Module`):

```
SuperscriptBox[Parenthesize[BoxForm`f, BoxForm`fmt, Power, Left], 
  RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ")"}]]
```

Comment: `??Parenthesize` gives _Parenthesize[ expr, fmt, prec, group] will represent expr in format fmt and parenthesize it if necessary._

Comment: @kglr did you forget to finish your comment?

Comment: QuantumDot, indeed:) I was hoping that someone could figure out what _prec_ and _group_  actually mean while i was strugling through docs stuff like [Notation/tutorial/PrecedenceOfOperatorsInNotations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/PrecedenceOfOperatorsInNotations.html) and [Notation/tutorial/ComplexPatternsAndAdvancedFeature](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/ComplexPatternsAndAdvancedFeatures.html)

Comment: Check this out: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Aug/msg00067.html

Comment: @M.R. I need to award bounty.  Can you write up an answer based on that link?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An good explanation can be found an old [mathgroup archive thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/Aug/msg00067.html) which I have reconstructed:

When you create a typeset form for a function or operator, you must write a MakeBoxes definition for that function. For example, if you want Transpose[A] to have the typeset form $A^T$ then you might, erroneously, write it this way:

```
  Transpose /: MakeBoxes[Transpose[matrix_], TraditionalForm] :=
    SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[matrix, TraditionalForm], "T"]
```

This is erroneous because Transpose[A + B] would typeset as $A + B^T$ which looks like A + Transpose[B], since superscripting by convention has higher precedence than addition.  You want it to typeset as $(A+B)^T$

To achieve this, the typesetting of 'matrix' in your definition must be informed of the context in which 'matrix' occurs, so that it can decide if the outermost operator in 'matrix' has a low enough precedence that it must be parenthesized.

> Parenthesize[] fits this bill, taking the same first two arguments as
>   MakeBoxes, ***and taking additional arguments to specify what the
>   enclosing operator is, and perhaps also on which side of it the
>   expression-to-be-typeset falls.***

So the correct rule for Transpose is:

```
  Transpose /: MakeBoxes[ Transpose[list_], TraditionalForm] :=
    SuperscriptBox[
      Parenthesize[list, TraditionalForm, Power, Left],
      "T"
    ]
```

This function probably ought to be mentioned somewhere, since it is
important, even if it is replaced with something better later.

Comment: Strictly speaking these rules should be defined directly on `MakeBoxes` rather than as upvalues on `Transpose`, both since the system is designed to work that way, and because `Transpose` is protected.

Comment: @OleksandrR , actually [according to @ItaiSeggev](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151532/2048), `TagSetDelayed` is preferable for `MakeBoxes`.  Do you believe he is in error?

Comment: @QuantumDot it is a different situation. For a user-defined function, obviously the definitions should be made on that, rather than on `MakeBoxes`. But `MakeBoxes` itself is deliberately not `Protected`, so that one can make definitions on it if desired (for example, if there's no better way to make them). `Transpose` *is* `Protected`, and moreover it is sufficiently fundamental a function that I can imagine it might lose "foreign" definitions without warning, like `Times` and `Plus` do.

Answer (score 8):

You can check also the docs for `PrecedenceForm` for examples. 
Precedence can be used to force parenthesization. If you put a low-ish number, you will likely get a parenthesis.
I am afraid I cannot help with  the fourth argument (group).

Comment: Do you mean to check docs for `PrecedenceForm`?  I think you're right about the third argument.

Comment: The third argument seems to work properly not with an `Integer` but with `Plus`, `Times` or `Power`.  I can't seem to find other Heads one can use in the third argument.

Comment: @QuantumDot  yes of course, edited. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple more comments about the use of the 3rd and 4th arguments of `Parenthesize`.

**Grouping**

First, the 4th argument is useful when the expression to be parenthesized is a binary infix operator that is left or right associative. For example, [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) is a binary operator that is right associative. It is a binary operator:

```
SyntaxInformation[Rule]
```

> {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _}}

It is right associative because that's how it parses:

```
a -> b -> c //FullForm
```

> Rule[a,Rule[b,c]]

This means that when [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule) is on the RHS of a rule it does not need parentheses, but when it is on the LHS it does need parentheses. This is exactly what `Parenthesize` returns:

```
Parenthesize[a -> b, StandardForm, Rule, Right]
Parenthesize[a -> b, StandardForm, Rule, Left]
```

> RowBox[{"a", "\[Rule]", "b"}]
>
> RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"a", "\[Rule]", "b"}], ")"}]

An example of a left associative operator is [`CircleMinus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleMinus):

```
SyntaxInformation[CircleMinus]
```

> {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _}}

It is left associative:

```
a ⊖ b ⊖ c //FullForm
```

> CircleMinus[CircleMinus[a,b],c]

When on the LHS no parentheses are needed, but they are needed on the RHS:

```
Parenthesize[a ⊖ b, StandardForm, CircleMinus, Left]
Parenthesize[a ⊖ b, StandardForm, CircleMinus, Right]
```

> RowBox[{"a", "⊖", "b"}]
>
> RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"a", "⊖", "b"}], ")"}]

**Numerical precedence**

Sometimes it's convenient to specify the precedence numerically instead of through a symbol. This can be done by using a list consisting of the precedence and grouping of the container. For example, [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) has precedence:

```
Precedence[Times]
```

> 400.

If you want to parenthesize an expression only when the precedence is less than [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times), you can use the list form in [`Parenthesize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parenthesize):

```
Parenthesize[a b, StandardForm, {399, None}]
Parenthesize[a b, StandardForm, {400, None}]
```

> RowBox[{"a", " ", "b"}]
>
> RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"a", " ", "b"}], ")"}]

You might wonder about using different grouping specifications (other than [`None`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/None)), but as far as I can tell the grouping specification never influences parenthesization. I could easily be wrong about this, though.