# Why does Parenthesize add parentheses here?

Tags: custom-notation, boxes

I've been playing around with the `` Notation` `` package and box forms for some custom notation recently. I discovered a nifty function named `Parenthesize`. You give it an expression and the function wrapping it (and technically a few other things, see the link), and it will produce a box output with parentheses automatically added it they are necessary for the expression to be properly formatted. There is a much better explanation and example here: [how-do-i-use-the-third-and-fourth-arguments-of-parenthesize](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113226/how-do-i-use-the-third-and-fourth-arguments-of-parenthesize).

I'm likely missing something obvious, but I don't understand its behavior here:

```
Parenthesize[2 x, StandardForm, Times]

(*evaluates to*)

RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"2", " ", "x"}], ")"}]
```

Why does it parenthesize `2 x` in the context of multiplication. `Times[___,Times[2,x],___]` reduces to `Times[___,2,x,___]` so the parentheses shouldn't be necessary right?

If I do not want the parentheses to show up, is it safe to use this instead: `Parenthesize[expr, StandardForm, 399, None]` because `Precedence[Times]` evaluates to `400`.